# Angular2: Infinite loop when adding component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have some rows and an array with column specifications. I loop through the rows and then through the columns and add TDs with some content.
As far as now it works.
But when I try to add components into these TDs or simply adding tags with [(ngModel)] specified the browser crashes.

Any ideas?

```js
columns = [
  {
    "name": "id",
    "text": "User ID"
  },
  {
    "name": "description",
    "text": "Description"
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "text": "Test"
  }
];

rowsFiltered = [
  {
    "checked": false,
    "id": "63",
    "name": "charvaldef-2",
    "description": {
      "html": ""
    },
    "test": {
      "dropdown": true,
      "multiple": false,
      "items": [
        {
          "value": "val1",
          "text": "Text 1",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "value": "val2",
          "text": "Text 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rowsFiltered;">
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns;">
                <ng-container *ngIf="col.name === 'test' && hasOwnProperty(row[col.name], 'dropdown')">
                    <input>
                    {{col.name}}
                </ng-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is typescript you can take advantage of `?.` which solves your problem in this case.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="col.name === 'test' && row[col.name]?.dropdown">
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggpmrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html)

If you want to persist with `hasOwnProperty` then you need to change your line to:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="col.name === 'test' && row[col.name].hasOwnProperty('dropdown')">
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any issues with the ngIf-Code in my ng-container. This is just testing.

I need a solution for adding [(ngModel)] to my input without crashing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I solved the problem by not iterating over columns but over an array of column names (string[]).

Still don't understand why this was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you were having a problem with this? Here is a repro where I'm doing a simple ngModel in each field, iterating over columns:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8anun8

Seems to be working fine! :)